# Clean up date/time data so Excel recognizes it

Tags: excel, date, data-cleaning

I have a column with the following date/time data and Excel doesn't recognize it as a date or time field. Does anyone know of an easy was to make this data usable?

Thanks in advance!

**Current Data:**

```
Completion Time Column
11/25/2013 @ 3:06PM
02/07/2012 @ 5:59PM
11/24/2013 @ 9:07AM
05/09/2013 @ 9:09AM
05/24/2013 @ 11:34AM
03/10/2013 @ 10:40PM
10/18/2012 @ 12:07PM
05/06/2014 @ 11:16AM
07/08/2014 @ 11:30AM
07/22/2014 @ 6:16PM
07/31/2014 @ 4:43PM
```

**Cleaned Up Data (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm):**

```
Completion Time Column
2013-11-25 15:06
2012-02-07 17:59
2013-11-24 09:07
2013-05-09 09:09
2013-05-24 11:34
2013-03-10 22:40
2012-10-18 12:07
2014-05-06 11:16
2014-07-08 11:30
2014-07-22 18:16
2014-07-31 16:43
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this formula

`=DATE(MID(A2, 7, 4), LEFT(A2, 2), MID(A2,4, 2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2),LEN(A2)-FIND(" @ ", A2)-4)&" "&RIGHT(A2,2))`

Answer (score -1):

Once you get the @ symbol out of the current data, you should be able to ctrl-d and select a date format or create your own.

Comment: I've tried that but it still can't recognize the time because the AM/PM are right next to the time with a space.

Answer (score -1):

Try this VBA module.

```
 Sub ConvertTheTime()

    Dim dateToConvert As Date
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Replace the @ so it is possible to work with the data/dates
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Replace " @ ", " ", xlPart
    End With

   ' Loop through each of the cells and convert them to date
   For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
          dateToConvert = CDate(cell)

         cell = Format$(dateToConvert, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No, he asked for an easy way. This is an easy way whether you like or not. And explain why it is an overkill? All other solutions, including yours, did not work.

Comment: Who are you to tell if it's an overkill or not? It takes 5 min to code and can be adjusted for further use if he has more worksheets or books. De facto is it is solving his issue.

Comment: This works perfectly. Pasted his data into column A, ran the script, got the output he wants. Amend the format as you want. Try it and stop hating.

Answer (score -1):

This formula is a bit messy but it will work everytime and format your result correctly:

```
=DATE(MID(F16, 7, 4), LEFT(F16, 2), MID(F16,4, 2))+TIME(MID(F16, 14, FIND(":", F16)-14), MID(F16, FIND(":", F16)+1, 2), 0)+IF(RIGHT(F16, 2) = "AM", 0, 0.5)
```

Note: I had your input in cell F16 so you will have to adjust accordingly, also note the if "PM" add 0.5 at the end handles the 24 hour time.

Also you want to format the result cell like this d/mm/yyyy HH:mm to display in 24 hour time

Comment: It is very close to working. For any time that is between 12:00 PM to 12:59 PM, it is treating it as AM and giving me 00:00 to 00:59

Comment: It's actualy changing the date too. 

    06/07/2016 @ 12:04PM 2016-06-08 00:04

Notice 6/7 becomes 6/8

Comment: sorry I did that pretty fast, I think its the right approach though you just need to tweak it slightly